# How to continue file transfer to LAN target on Windows?

Tags: windows-7, networking, file-transfer

I have a big file, and I wanted to copy it to the other machine. (Both runs on Windows 7 x64.)
The network speed is terrible, so it took hours to get even 25gigs copied over.  And then, the network died.

Now I would like to continue the transfer, but I used Total Commander. It can overwrite the file and such, but I want to continue. I'd prefer to continue, and keep the already copied portion.

What software can do this?
I've checked Robocopy, TeraCopy and Total Commander. No luck so far.

Comment: Hmm, I could swear I have seen a "resume" option in Total Commander though. Will check tomorrow.

Comment: @grawity - I thought the same. But it couldn't continue. Append is an option, but it's meant to be used for text files for example. :/

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe that any program exists that can resume a copy started by a different program.  To resume a partial transfer you would have to use the same program that started it, assuming it supports that (and it sounds like yours doesn't).  With a network that flaky, I would suggest copying it via USB drive.  If you don't have a USB drive large enough to fit the entire file, you can break it up using a tool like [File Splitter](http://www.filesplitter.org/) and transfer it a piece at a time.  Actually, doing it this way and using two drives (1 to copy from source and 1 to copy to destination, simultaneously) would effectively double your throughput.

Comment: *"unless the program you were using to copy it supports that (and it sounds like yours doesn't)."* – And the question happens to be "what software can do this?"

Comment: True, but it sounds like the OP is asking what program can resume a copy started by Total Commander.  Since Total Commander apparently doesn't support it, I don't think there exists anything that could take over that particular copy, so I was suggesting an alternate faster/safer method.  Poor wording on my part...  I will edit my response.

Comment: What about rsync?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend splitting the file with [HJSplit](http://www.hjsplit.org/) and then copying each file over one by one. Then, on the target computer, you can combine the files.

[image: HJSplit screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

Standard command line tool **XCOPY** could resume copying files after connection was broken. If you do such tasks from time to time, to create a .cmd file with xcopy command could be acceptable solution. It's much easier than split files and use usb sticks.
Type xcopy /? in command line to check syntaxis.

Answer (score 0):

[Multicommander](http://multicommander.com/) can resume downloading files. 
Let's assume the partly downloaded file has the same name as the source file.
You should start copying the file into the same destination.
You will get a window with a message that there is already a file with the same name.
You can click "Resume" button and it should continue downloading the file.

[image: screenshot]